# Multiple buttons in CSS + Button with an image not showing properly

Tags: css, button

Currently trying to build a webpage for my small compagny.  Let's just say that it's been a while since I coded and I never used CSS before NOW! :)

Here is my problems:

**Problem #1**
I have several buttons (7) in a row and my last button has an image inside instead of text. 
 The button that has an image inside of it isn't aligned with the other buttons!
[image: Button now showing properly]

I reduced my `img` from 25px to 15px `height` but the button still sticks to the upper border.  
I've added `height:100px` to .myButton in order to test if it was still the image... But as you can see on this picture... it is not the problem.  (I've updated my new code)

[image: Still not working]
***Problem #2*** (SOLVED THANKS!!!)
I would like to create all the buttons equal!  Right now they all have different length  How could I do that?

Here is my current code!  Thanks

```css
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; /* !!! */
}
#button {
 margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    width:768px;
    padding:0px;
 display: flex;       
}
.myButton {
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f0e1b7), color-stop(1, #f7be14));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f0e1b7', endColorstr='#f7be14',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#f0e1b7;
 -moz-border-radius:6px;
 -webkit-border-radius:6px;
 border-radius:6px;
 border:2px solid #969187;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#333333;
 font-family:arial;
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:5px 16px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffee66;
 width:70px;
 height:100px;

}

.myButton:hover {
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f7be14), color-stop(1, #f0e1b7));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f7be14', endColorstr='#f0e1b7',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#f7be14;
}
.myButton:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="button" align="center">
 <a href="#" class="myButton">Entreprise</a>
    <a href="#" class="myButton">Produits</a>
 <a href="#" class="myButton">Services</a>
 <a href="#" class="myButton">Photos</a>
 <a href="#" class="myButton">Références</a>
 <a href="#" class="myButton">Calculs Ing.</a>
 <a href="#" class="myButton"><img src="Image/Boutons/usine.png"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can post an image now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using a background image

A background image is a better choice semantically here as the image is mainly decoration.

The button containing the image is given a class, `.imageLink`, and appropriate text matching the contents of the page linked to. The text will be removed in the CSS, but will still be indexed by search engines.

The image replacement button looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="myButton imageLink">Image Link</a>
```

and the CSS. The text is removed with `text-indent: -9999px;` and the image is placed as a background (before the gradient background is given). The height matches the background image height:

```
.imageLink {
  background:url(http://www.placehold.it/50) center no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);  
  text-indent: -9999px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Finally, the links are kept as `display: inline-block` but with the addition of `vertical-align: bottom` to align them vertically to the bottom of the image button.

### Complete Example

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /* !!! */
}
#button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 768px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.myButton {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f0e1b7), color-stop(1, #f7be14));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f0e1b7', endColorstr='#f7be14', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #f0e1b7;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 2px solid #969187;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffee66;
  width: 70px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.myButton:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f7be14), color-stop(1, #f0e1b7));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f7be14', endColorstr='#f0e1b7', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #f7be14;
}
.myButton:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
.imageLink {
  background: url(http://www.placehold.it/50) center no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
  text-indent: -9999px;
  height: 50px;
}

.imageLink:hover {
  background: url(http://www.placehold.it/50) center no-repeat, linear-gradient(to top, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
  <a href="#" class="myButton">Entreprise</a>
  <a href="#" class="myButton">Produits</a>
  <a href="#" class="myButton">Services</a>
  <a href="#" class="myButton">Photos</a>
  <a href="#" class="myButton">Références</a>
  <a href="#" class="myButton">Calculs Ing.</a>
  <a href="#" class="myButton imageLink">Image Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make all buttons have the same size, you can use flexible boxes:

```css
#button {
    display: flex;            /* Same height */
}
.myButton {
    width: 100%;              /* Same width */
}
```

And to center the text vertically inside the buttons, you can use flexible boxes too:

```css
.myButton {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;      /* Center vertically */
    justify-content: center;  /* Center horizontally */
}
```

```css
#button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 768px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.myButton {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f0e1b7), color-stop(1, #f7be14));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0e1b7 5%, #f7be14 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f0e1b7', endColorstr='#f7be14', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #f0e1b7;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 2px solid #969187;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffee66;
}
.myButton:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f7be14), color-stop(1, #f0e1b7));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7be14 5%, #f0e1b7 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f7be14', endColorstr='#f0e1b7', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #f7be14;
}
.myButton:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

#button {
  display: flex;
}
.myButton {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="button" align="center">
  <a href="#" class="myButton">Entreprise</a>
  <a href="#" class="myButton">Produits</a>
  <a href="#" class="myButton">Services</a>
  <a href="#" class="myButton">Photos</a>
  <a href="#" class="myButton">Références</a>
  <a href="#" class="myButton">Calculs Ing.</a>
  <a href="#" class="myButton">
    <img src="Image/Boutons/usine.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Width 100% makes all my button take all the page! :P

Comment: @Konsume No, because you have `#button{width:768px}`

Answer (score 0):

The image inside your button is too big.
You should make your image smaller and just in case, 
specify the height for your buttons.

```
.myButton {
height: 40px; /* Whatever height you want */
}

.myButton img {
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
}
```

EDIT: You could also make the image your button's background
in order to fit it in the button.

```
.myButton #imgbutton {
background-image: url('Image/Boutons/usine.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
}
```

The HTML would like this:

```
<a href="#" class="myButton">
<img id="imgbutton"  src="Image/Boutons/usine.png">
</a>
```

Alternatively, you could make all the buttons a bit taller, like in the second image
and center the content.

```
.myButton a {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

What comes to the second problem, it's as easy as the previous one.
You just need to specify a common width for your buttons.

```
.myButton {
width: 60px; /* Whatever width you want */
}
```

The final code would look like this:

```
.myButton {
height: 40px; /* Whatever height you want */
}

.myButton img {
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my newbiness but how would I call the .myButton #imgbutton { in the HTML part?

Comment: I tried <a href="#" class="myButton" id="imgbutton"></a> but it didn't work!

Answer (score -1):

The reason the image button is not aligned, is because the content inside it is larger than text, there are two solutions to this:

1. Decrease the height of the image inside the button
2. Increase the height of the text buttons by manually calculating the height of the image button and matching it (which can be achieved by `height:100px` in `.mybuttons`.

Regarding the second problem (same width), set `width: 90px;`.

In `.myButton` can achieve same width across buttons (change the 90 to whatever number you feel is best).